# Rails alternative to including active record call in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I have a form partial that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@pool) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tournament %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :tournament_id, Tournament.active, :id, :name, :prompt => true %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This seems like a code smell because the view shouldn't be responsible for knowing how to get the data for the `<select>` tag. The alternative to have the controller assign an instance variable is problematic because I have to replicate that code in several actions depending on whether or not this form is rendered.

In ASP.NET MVC I'd just pull that field out into a partial view and display it with a call to `RenderAction` Which would evaluate a common controller action. However, in Rails `render :action => '/view'` seems to only allow full blown views to be rendered. I'm pretty new to Rails so I'm not sure about what the best practices are.

Comment: I don't quite grasp what you are asking. I don't know if it's of any help, but you can call `render :partial => 'file'` from within a partial rendering.

Comment: Maybe a helper method would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a helper method as coder_tim suggests, but in my opinion that still leaves data access in the view.

The controller is the proper place for this and if you're worried about duplication, set up a before_filter that only acts on the actions that need this collection:

```
before_filter :get_active_tournaments, :only => [:new, :edit]
```

for example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: awesome, I had thought about a helper method, but a helper method that called through to one other method seemed like over engineering, just for the sake of creating an abstraction. This is exactly the kind of rails oriented solution I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

I like the smell of that code :) Simplicity over extremism. Less files = less methods to worry = cleaner code.

However, there are times when a dropdown is used too many times in your application, and it's a little more complicated than just calling a scope. In that cases, I write a helper.

Comment: There's definitely a part of me that thinks that since it's simple it's probably fine too. As developers we're often overengineering because we've been taught that abstractions are good practice.